# Is there a way in selenium to upload the last downloaded file with dynamic name?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The problem I am facing is I have a file which is having a dynamic number at the last.

For example: `Tax_subscription_124.pdf` which changes everytime.

Can I upload this particular file as currently I am downloading it in a particular location but not able to upload the same due to dynamic name?

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns the last modified file or folder:

```
public static File getLastModified(String directoryFilePath)
{
    File directory = new File(directoryFilePath);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles(File::isFile);
    long lastModifiedTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    File chosenFile = null;

    if (files != null)
    {
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (file.lastModified() > lastModifiedTime)
            {
                chosenFile = file;
                lastModifiedTime = file.lastModified();
            }
        }
    }

    return chosenFile;
}
```

Note that it required Java 8 or newer due to the lambda expression.

After that

```
WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.name("uploadfile"));
fileInput.sendKeys(chosenFile);
```